# Show CSS colors with BBEdit?

Tags: css, highlighting, bbedit

Can BBEdit show the actual color inline in a CSS or SASS file? Some text editors when you type the following will give the `#3399FF` a highlight of that color (in this case blue). This can be helpful when browsing CSS or SASS files.

```
.something {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```